# How get all url images in a page with JSoup?

Tags: java, web-crawler, jsoup

I'm using JSoup to crawler pages. I usually need get all url's imagens inside a page or a piece of page and put then in a `ArrayList<String>`. Suposed the follow document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>News Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="news">
      <div class="new">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="../images/img01.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <p class="title">
            Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="new">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="../images/img02.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <p class="title">
            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="new">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="../images/img03.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <p class="title">
            Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I do it on this way:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements images = document.select(img);

ArrayList<String> binaryUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Element image : images) {
    binaryUrls.add(image.absUrl("src"));
}
```

And the result:

```
['http//www.newssite.com/images/img01.jpg', 'http//www.newssite.com/images/img02.jpg', 'http//www.newssite.com/images/img03.jpg']
```

It works, but I want know if exists a short way, just with Jsoup to do it.

In a production envirioment we used Java 6, yet. If possible, I liked know a Java 6 mode and a Java 8 mode, with lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No suggestion for Java6.

Using Lambda in Java 8:

```
ArrayList<String> binaryUrls = Jsoup.parse(html).select("img")
    .stream().map(p -> p.absUrl("src"))
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Or if the return type can be just `List<String>`:

```
List<String> binaryUrls = Jsoup.parse(html).select("img")
    .stream().map(p -> p.absUrl("src"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```